# save picture in database table

Tags: java

I have a question. I am making a project using databases. When I insert a new row into my table, I also add a picture. My question, is what is the best way to store pictures in the database? I tried using different ways.

1. Store the path to the folder with pictures in the database.
2. Store pictures in the database with the blog type.

The problem is that in both ways, the pictures are slow in switching when I click on JTable to switch them. Can you give suggestions on how to do it the proper way? I would really appreciate the help.
Here is my code:

```
private void jTable2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        jButton1.setEnabled(true);
    Database base =  new Database();
        model =  (DefaultTableModel)jTable2.getModel();
    int selectedRowIndex = jTable2.getSelectedRow();


        //find picture in forlder and change jLabel2 for image 
        base.findImageDerictory(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 1).toString(), jLabel2 );






} 

public void findImageDerictory(String name, JLabel jLabel2) {



    //GET TYPE OF IMAGE
    /*String[] path1 = name.split("\\.");

    String ext = path1[path1.length - 1];
    // your directory
    File f = new File("/Computer/eclipce-projects/NewDataBase/resource");
    File[] matchingFiles = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.startsWith(name) && name.endsWith(ext);
        }
    });*/

    try {
                data = getmyConnection(); 
                st = data.createStatement();



        //CallableStatement statement = null;
        //Connection data = getmyConnection(); 
        //statement = data.prepareCall("{call get_picture(?)}");


        //statement.setString(1, name);
        //statement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);


 myResults = st.executeQuery("SELECT *  FROM students_table WHERE  Name = '"+name+"'");

            if(myResults.next() ) {
                             byte[]  img = myResults.getBytes("Picture");
                              ImageIcon firstIcon = new ImageIcon(img);
                             Image  im = firstIcon.getImage();
                               Image my_image = im.getScaledInstance(jLabel2.getWidth(), 
                                       jLabel2.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                               ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon(my_image);
                               jLabel2.setIcon(newIcon);
                            } else {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Data!!!");
                            }



    } catch (Exception c) {
        c.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The problem appears when I click on the table. Sometimes it is slow, sometimes id doesn't get the name from the jtable. May you help me?

Comment: What is really your problem? You can try to debug/benchmark each method to see what is the root cause of the slowness? Don't just assume it by the DB, and you should put some code for us to see if where the problem comes from.

Comment: I think the loading speed does not depend on where you store you picture in your case, you should find out the cause. However, storing picture in database is not a good practice.

Comment: I am using this method to swith the picture by click on jtable:

Comment: private void jTable2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
            jButton1.setEnabled(true);
        Database base =  new Database();
            model =  (DefaultTableModel)jTable2.getModel();
     int selectedRowIndex = jTable2.getSelectedRow();
        
            
            //find picture in forlder and change jLabel2 for image 
            base.findImageDerictory(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 1).toString(), jLabel2 );
       
                
           
            
            
          
    }

Comment: after i go to database and compare name from the row with data

Comment: st.executeQuery("SELECT *  FROM students_table WHERE  Name = '"+name+"'");

Comment: I think a problem appears when I click on JTable

Comment: May anyone help me to show how to get a name from JTable by click?

Comment: The solution is to benchmark your code to find out where is the slowdown happening, and then work from there.

Comment: May you post a piece of code? I don't know where to find a problem?